# Create time between execution of 2 functions(plain javascript)

Tags: javascript, timing

I want to have a set amount of time between my explosion function and the reset function, if I don't have a set amount of time, the code quickly executes the reset function after the execution function. This makes the explosion basically invisible. I tried setting a timeOut on the reset function, but that didn't change anything.

Here is the code:

```
  function loop(){
    //game code up here
    if(out){
      //run explode for certain amount of time then call reset function
      explode();
      //setTimeout(reset, time)
      reset();
    }
  }
  setInterval(loop, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript 1.7, using yield with [async.js](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/pausing-javascript-with-async-js), you can do the following:

```
    function loop(){
    //game code up here
    if(out){
      //run explode for certain amount of time then call reset function
      explode();
      //setTimeout(reset, time)
      yield to.sleep(.500)
      reset();
    }
  }
```

If you want to use it only with plain javascript, you can try following,

```
function loop() {
    //game code up here
    if (out) {
        explode();
    }
}

function explode() {
    //explode code goes here
    setTimeout(reset, 3000);
}
loop();
```

Comment: If async.js is a library, how might I get it?

Comment: I added plain javascript way to my answer

Answer (score 0):

As @Channa mentioned in above answer setTimeout will execute your reset function, once after 1000 milliseconds. Better if you wrap it like this, otherwise your reset function will run straight away.

```
setTimeout(function() { reset(); }, 1000);
```

In addition, if you want to call your function repeatedly, you can use this.

```
setInterval(reset,1000);
```

setInterval will call your reset function after every 1000 ms.

Comment: Correction: I want to call the explode function repeatedly a few times for a set amount of time, because the explosion isn't rendering.

Comment: That is logical thinking :) Take time and think.